# XLST Recursive Coalesce?

Tags: xslt

I have a sparse dataset where three related elements should be coalesced into one.  In this example they are `a`, `b`, and `c`, and the order of preference is also `a`, `b`, and `c`.  An element is skipped if it missing or has empty-ish content.

**Source Data**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
    <a>foo1</a>
    <b>foo1.1</b>
    <c>foo1.1</c>
  </row>
  <row>
    <b>foo2.1</b>
    <c>foo2.2</c>
  </row>
  <row>
    <a></a>
    <b>foo3.2</b>
  </row>
  <row>
    <c>foo4.3</c>
  </row>
</root>
```

**Ideal Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <row>
      <a>foo1</a>
   </row>
   <row>
      <a>foo2.1</a>
   </row>
   <row>
      <a>foo3.2</a>
   </row>
   <row>
      <a>foo4.3</a> <!-- My current stylesheet emits 'b' here -->
   </row>
</root>
```

**Acceptable Output**
Redundant values left in document.. they'll be ignored anyway

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <row>
      <a>foo1</a>
      <b>foo1.1</b>
      <c>foo1.1</c>
   </row>
   <row>
      <a>foo2.1</a>
      <c>foo2.2</c>
   </row>
   <row>
      <a>foo3.2</a>
   </row>
   <row>
      <a>foo4.3</a>
   </row>
</root>
```

**My Stylesheet**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- throw out blanks -->
    <xsl:template match="b[normalize-space(text()) = '']" />
    <xsl:template match="a[normalize-space(text()) = '']" />

  <!-- bubble c up to b -->
  <xsl:template match="c[normalize-space(../b) = '']">
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </b>
    </xsl:template>
    

  <!-- bubble b up to a -->
    <xsl:template match="b[normalize-space(../a) = '']">
        <a>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I assumed that the functional nature of XSLT would cause the new instances of `b` and `c` to be run through the preceding template, "bubbling" them to the top.  If in the `xsl:apply-templates` element I could specify the new name I think I'd be in business.

My problem space does have a fixed recursion depth of three so I could solve this problem with an additional template which promotes `c` up to `c`

Context: Saxon-HE v10 (so XLST 3.0)

[XSLT Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/) is a great tool for working with this stuff.

Comment: In your desired output, should the elements in the second row be <a> and <b> instead of <a> and <c> as posted?

Comment: @Sebastien Yes, if the solution was truly recursive I do believe that the it would have a and b.  Good catch!  I've clarified the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "recursive coalesce" or "bubbling" means. It seems to me that the result you show could be produced simply by:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:copy>
        <a>
            <xsl:value-of select="(a, b, c)[normalize-space(.)][1]"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Very elegant!  Thanks for the wisdom.